# Making a follow system with firestore and cloud functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi I am attempting to make a social media app on Firestore.

Now to model a follow system here is my plan.

- users (Collection)

  - {uid} document which contains Followers and Following as a number.
- following (Collection)

  - {uid}

    - myFollowing (subCollection)

      - {uid of other user}
- followers (Collection)

  - {uid}

    - myFollowers (subCollection)

      - {uid of other user}

So here is my plan, and please feel free to critique it and help me make it better, because I dont know if this is the best way to do it.

When user A follows user B, I will write a document in:

- following

  - A uid

    - myFollowing

      - B uid

This write will happen straight from the app.

After which I plan to trigger a cloud function that does two things, 1. It will increment a counter in the users collection, that holds total following. 2. It will write another document which would be

- Followers

  - B uid

    - myFollowers

      - A uid

And after this I can have another cloud function that triggers whenever a document is made in the Followers/uid/myFollowers collection which increments followers count in the users collection.

So here are the questions

1. Is this the best way to go about this?
2. How do i write the cloud functions?

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by doing everything I did above, and using the following code for cloud functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.onFollowCreate = functions.firestore
    .document("following/{userID}/myFollowing/{id}")
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const newValue = snap.data()
        const db = admin.firestore();
        db.collection("users").doc(context.params.userID).update({following: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)}).catch((er)=>{console.log(er)})
        db.collection('followers').doc(newValue.uid).collection("myFollowers").doc(context.params.userID).set({uid: context.params.userID, timeStamp: new Date()}).catch(er=>console.log(er))

    });

exports.onFollowDelete = functions.firestore
    .document("following/{userID}/myFollowing/{id}")
    .onDelete((snap, context)=>{
        const deletedValue = snap.data()
        const db = admin.firestore();
        db.collection("users").doc(context.params.userID).update({following: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)}).catch(er=>console.log(er))
        db.collection('followers').doc(deletedValue.uid).collection("myFollowers").doc(context.params.userID).delete().catch(er=>console.log(er))
    })

exports.onFollowersCreate = functions.firestore
    .document("followers/{userID}/myFollowers/{id}")
    .onCreate((snap, context)=>{
        const db = admin.firestore();
        db.collection("users").doc(context.params.userID).update({followers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)}).catch(er=>console.log(er))
    })

exports.onFollowersDelete = functions.firestore
    .document("followers/{userID}/myFollowers/{id}")
    .onDelete((snap, context)=>{
        const db = admin.firestore();
        db.collection("users").doc(context.params.userID).update({followers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)}).catch(er=>console.log(er))
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I've thought of this before and it was very similar. I think this might be the best way to go about structuring your database. [Here's an article](https://medium.com/@Alibaba_Cloud/pcc-social-media-like-scenario-database-design-and-performance-stress-testing-e29edf3394b3) on Medium about some database designs.

Now for the functions, you want one which will trigger once you write that document about A following B. See [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) for a `onCreate` function. Your cloud functions will live in a node.js 10 serverless environment and will have no connection to your front-end application. [Here's a real world example](https://github.com/herbievine/herbievine/blob/master/functions/index.js) of some of my functions on a deployed site. I would recommend not adding data to firestore on your front-end. Instead make a `onCall` HTTP function, [see more about those here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function).

Sorry for not giving you actual code to go off of, but I find doing it yourself will help you learn. Good luck :)

Comment: Why shouldnt I directly add data to firestore through the front end application? I am making very sure that firestore rules are being properly set, and that it cannot be taken advantage of.

Comment: Well it's not technically a bad thing it's more for simplicity sake. If you have document Reads, writes, updates and all that it various places, it can get messy

Comment: Most of my writing is done on the front end, there is only some things that I want to do using cloud functions because of security concerns. Because I dont want users to have the ability to update other users follower counts, this can be broken badly! But I dont want to do everything on cloud functions, because that is unnecessarily invocation costs.

Comment: Yeah no worries it's not a bad thing.... do you need anymore help?

Comment: Sort of, I wrote 4 different functions using your guidance, I have updated my question with the code for this. The problem is the functions dont work, can you take a look?

Comment: I'm guessing you've uploaded the to firebase and all that right? You can also console.log() in you functions and it will show up under logs in the functions tab in firebase. It's quite hard just from looking at them to see any issues... but logging will help. I don't see any syntax errors anyways...

Comment: actually I solved the problem, it was a few syntax errors. Ill update the code with the solution